# Google Apps Scriptでスクリプト関数 sendEmails が見つかりませんというエラー

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

フォームで送られてきたものをスプレットシートに表示させ、その中のメールアドレスと名前を使用して、ドキュメントに作ったメッセージ本文を一括送信するという仕組みをつくりたいです。

送信しようとしましたら

> メッセージの詳細
>   スクリプト関数 sendEmails が見つかりません。詳しくは https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String) をご覧ください。

とエラーが出てきてしまいました。

しかし、いろいろやってみたのですが、何が間違っているのかどうすればいいかわかりませんでした。

プログラム初心者でもわかるようにお願いできればうれしいです。

以下が記載したコードです。

```
function myFunction() {
  Browser.msgBox("Hello " + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
}

function myFunction() {
  var SheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var SheetRow = SheetName.getDataRange().getLastRow();

  /* ドキュメント「メール本文テスト」を取得する */
  var docMail = DocumentApp.openById("1***********8"); //ドキュメントのID
  var strDoc = docMail.getBody().getText();

  /* シートの全ての行について姓名を差し込みログに表示*/
  for (var i = 2; i <= SheetRow; i++) {
    var strToAd = SheetName.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var strName = SheetName.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var strBody = strDoc.replace(/{お名前}/g, strName);

    /* メール表題、fromアドレス、差出人名を準備 */
    var strSubj = "************"; //タイトル
    var strFrom = "************"; //Fromのアドレス
    var strSend = "**************"; //差出人の名前

    /* メールを送信 */
    GmailApp.sendEmail(strToAd, strSubj, strBody, {
      from: strFrom,
      name: strSend
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！質問に掲載するソースコードは、画像だと読みにくいので直接貼り付けるようにしていただけると助かります（貼り付け後、選択して `{}` をクリックすることでハイライティングが可能です）。

Comment: さて、今回の質問ですが、エラーメッセージの内容を確認するにメールではなく `Menu.addItem` というメソッドの中でエラーが起きているようですが、記載されているコードを確認する限りそのような内容が見つかりません。記載されているソースコードは正しいですか？

Comment: ＞PicoSushi様　早速のご返信誠にありがとうございます！！　返信をどこですればいいのかわからず、コメントから失礼いたします。ソースコードを添付します。↓↓↓

Comment: function myFunction() {
  Browser.msgBox("Hello " + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
}

function myFunction(){
　var SheetName=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
　var SheetRow=SheetName.getDataRange().getLastRow();

 
/* ドキュメント「メール本文テスト」を取得する */
　var docMail=DocumentApp.openById("1***********8"); //ドキュメントのID
　var strDoc=docMail.getBody().getText();

Comment: /* シートの全ての行について姓名を差し込みログに表示*/
　for(var i=2;i<=SheetRow;i++){

 
　　var strToAd=SheetName.getRange(i,2).getValue();
　　var strName=SheetName.getRange(i,3).getValue();


 
　　var strBody=strDoc.replace(/{お名前}/g,strName);

   
    
/* メール表題、fromアドレス、差出人名を準備 */
　var strSubj="************"; //タイトル
　var strFrom="************"; //Fromのアドレス
　var strSend="**************"; //差出人の名前

   

/* メールを送信 */
　　GmailApp.sendEmail(
　　　strToAd,
　　　strSubj,
　　　strBody,
　　　{
　　　　from: strFrom,
　　　　name: strSend
　　　}
　　);

 

　}
}

Comment: 以上がコードになります。読みづらくなってしまい申し訳ございません。コードはコピペからの修正を自分なりに考えたり調べたりして変更していったのですが、『”』がエラーと出たので直したのと、名前のフォームが姓名一緒の欄にしてしまっているので、コピペした内容では姓名が別の場合だったので、それをオリジナルから変えました。またフォームの関係でスプレットシートのA列は「送られてきた時間」、B列が「メールアドレス」、C列が「お名前」となってましたので数字を変えてます（例：getRange(i,2)、getRange(i,3)）。またスプレットシートのタイトルがフォームのほうで「メールアドレス」「お名前」となっていたのでそのようにタイトル表記（スプレットシートの横列の1行目）されていたのですが、もしやそれで読み込まないのかとおもい、タイトルを「Email」「Name」に変更したのですが、それは関係あるのかないのかわからずじまいです。また、ご回答いただいた内容についてご質問なのですが『貼り付け後、選択して {} をクリックすることでハイライティングが可能です』とは例えばどのようにすることなのでしょうか?｛｝をつけるといろが付くという認識でよろしいでしょうか？その場合コードにも｛｝がついているのですが、混同したりしないでしょうか？つたない内容で申し訳ございませんが、ご回答何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

『スクリプト関数 sendEmails が見つかりません』というエラーメッセージが出たのは、
コメント欄に書かれたコード

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(strToAd, strSubj, strBody, { from: strFrom, name: strSend });
```

のように  "sendEmail"関数を使うべきところをミスタイプして、"sendEmails"と書いてしまったからではないですか？

Google App Scriptに"sendEmail"関数はありますが、"sendEmails"関数はありませんから、『スクリプト関数 sendEmails が見つかりません』というエラーメッセージが出たという当たり前の話のような気がします。

＝＝＝
＜何が間違っているのか＞
　"sendEmail"と書くところを、"sendEmails"と書いてしまった（最後に余分な s が入ってしまった）

＜どうすればよいのか＞
　・問題をおこしたのプログラムの中で、"sendEmails"という文字列を探す。
　・それが"sendEmail"を使うべきところであれば、修正(余分な最後の文字 's'を削除）する。

Answer (score 0):

具体的に記載くださいまして本当にありがとうございます！
sendEmailが使われているのは、

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(strToAd, strSubj, strBody, { from: strFrom, name: strSend });
```

のところのみみたいです。自分の目でチェックしたのとDreamWeaverで検索もしてみたのですが見当たらなかったです。

もしかしてソース的に足りない記載があるのでしょうか？
いろんな記事からもってきて入れ替えて試してもみたのですが、だいたいこのエラーが出ます。

> ```
> 詳しくは https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)
> ```
>
> をご覧ください。

ともあったので、Google翻訳なので理解はできてないとおもうのですが、(String,String)の記載あるところがあったのでみると、大文字とか小文字の問題なのかとおもいみてみたのですが、コードの記載のルールがいまいちわからないので、ほかの部分と統一してさがしてみたりもしたのですが、見つけられませんでした。

もしくはほかの設定、スプレットシートやドキュメントのほうでもなにかスクリプトエディタで記載しないといけないとかありますでしょうか？自分が行き当たった記事にはそっちの設定のスクリプトエディタについては書いてなかったので、現在探しています。

もしなにかお分かりになることがございましたら何卒よろしくお願いいたします。